# Send email in PHP with variable emailadress?

Tags: php, email, hosting, sendmail

I am using the php `mail()` function to send emails and I was wondering if it possible to send emails from a variable email adress, without creating every adress in the hosting provider.

I am asking this question because of a requirement from a client, I am building a webshop for. What my client wants is adding the name of the product, with the order date in the emailadress before the '@'-sign.

So an example of code would look like this:

```
$headers = array(
            'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
            'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1',
            'From' => $orderName . '_' . $month . '@example.org',
            'To' => $email, 
            'Bcc' => $BCCemail,
        );
mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

So what I am wondering is: Will the server send this email with the variables in From header?

Comment: This sounds like a question for your hosting provider.

Comment: @Dave It probably is, but maybe someone can answer this question from experience and with theories how email works

Comment: "Email" as such (as in, the email infrastructure), doesn't care much about what you put into the optional `From` header. *Specific* parts of *your* infrastructure might (e.g. your host might only allow you to send "from" verified addresses).

Comment: Thanks, I think it might be worth trying this on the web. What do i got to lose?

Comment: Experience and knowing how email works won't help in this situation really. We don't know what provider you use or what their rules are so anything provided to answer your question would be a guess at best. deceze provided about the only information possible based on what you provided.

Comment: Allright thanks for the help both of you @Dave

Comment: and also thanks to you @deceze